# Сайт на WordPress перестал отвечать

Tags: wordpress

Страницы на сайте на Wordpress независимо редактировались двумя людьми.
Что-то произошло, и у одного человека перестал отвечать сайт (скриншот ниже). У другого человека сайт по-прежнему работает, и он может его редактировать.

В чём может быть причина неполадки?

[результат http://img4.tempfile.ru/14170/1376ecfe55/4eef04f1793cd86084710fd6.jpg](http://img4.tempfile.ru/14170/1376ecfe55/4eef04f1793cd86084710fd6.jpg)

Comment: Вот скрин

http://img4.tempfile.ru/14170/1376ecfe55/4eef04f1793cd86084710fd6.jpg

Comment: 1) проверили связь?  2) сервер не меняли? 3) домены работают?

Comment: Оказалась проблема в роутере. Потому что с другого ip сайт открывается. Но странно, почему именно тот сайт не открывается через тот роутер, а другие сайты открываются. Но это, наверное, вопрос из другой области, и нужно задавать на другом портале знаний.